# can not use dplyr programming syntax in across() in r

Tags: r, dplyr, evaluation

I want to use dplyr programming syntax (combine `!!` and `:=`) to evaluate a function in `.fn` argument but failed.
The code like this:

```
library(zoo)
library(glue)

aa = structure(list(region = c(1, 2, 3, 4), co_mean = c(5, 5, 5, 5
), o3_mean = c(5, 5, 5, 5), pm2.5_mean = c(5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


for (i in 1:3) {
  
fun_name_1 = glue('lag{i}')
fun_name_2 = glue('lag0{i}')
aa = aa %>% group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = contains('mean'), 
                .fns = list(!!fun_name_1 := ~lag(., i), # ERROR OCCUR AT HERE
                            !!fun_name_2 := ~ rollmeanr(., i)),
                .names = '{.col}_{.fn}'))
aa
}
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

======UPDATE========

My new code and new ERROR:

```
library(zoo)
library(glue)

aa = structure(list(region = c(1, 2, 3, 4), co_mean = c(5, 5, 5, 5
), o3_mean = c(5, 5, 5, 5), pm2.5_mean = c(5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


for (i in 1:3) {
 # i <- 1
  fun_name_1 = glue('lag{i}')
  fun_name_2 = glue('lag0{i}')
  aa %>%
    group_by(region) %>% 
    mutate(across(.cols = contains('mean'), 
                  .fns = setNames(list(~lag(., i),
                                       ~ rollmeanr(., i)), c(fun_name_1, fun_name_2)),
                  .names = '{.col}_{.fn}'))
aa
}

# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
# x 'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [5]
# i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
# i The error occurred in group 1: region = 1.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: I guess even the `lag` for a single observation creates only `NA` (as there is only an element for each group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work as a named `list`.  It makes perfect sense to pass a group by first (assuming that the OP's original example data have multiple rows per group)

```
i <- 1
fun_name_1 = glue('lag{i}')
fun_name_2 = glue('lag0{i}')
aa %>%
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = contains('mean'), 
               .fns = setNames(list(~lag(., i),
                         ~ rollmeanr(., i)), c(fun_name_1, fun_name_2)),
                .names = '{.col}_{.fn}'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 10
# Groups:   region [4]
#  region co_mean o3_mean pm2.5_mean co_mean_lag1 co_mean_lag01 o3_mean_lag1 o3_mean_lag01 pm2.5_mean_lag1 pm2.5_mean_lag01
#   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
#1      1       5       5          5           NA             5           NA             5              NA                5
#2      2       5       5          5           NA             5           NA             5              NA                5
#3      3       5       5          5           NA             5           NA             5              NA                5
#4      4       5       5          5           NA             5           NA             5              NA
```

---

Could specify the `fill = TRUE` in `rollmean`

```
aa %>%
   group_by(region) %>% 
   mutate(across(.cols = contains('mean'), 
                .fns = setNames(list(~lag(., i),
                          ~ rollmeanr(., i, fill = TRUE)), c(fun_name_1, fun_name_2)),
                 .names = '{.col}_{.fn}'))
```

Comment: It was run correctly when i = 1, but when I use your code in the loop, an error occur:```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x 'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [5]
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: region = 1.```

Comment: @zhiweili can you show your `dplyr` `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: @zhiweili I am using `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.2’`

Comment: it is ‘1.0.2’ of my `dplyr`

Comment: @zhiweili and my `glue` is `packageVersion('glue')#
[1] ‘1.4.1’`.  I double checked again and it is working fine for me

Comment: my `glue` is `packageVersion('glue')# [1] ‘1.4.2’`

Comment: @zhiweili updated with `1.4.2` and it is still working for me

Comment: I update my new code and new error in my question. Is the new code works for you and do you see the error I post?

Comment: @zhiweili it has nothing to do with the `setNames`.  If you check `i <- 2`, it is the `rollmean` that creates the issue because you are grouping by 'region' and there is only a single element per group, `rollmeanr(1)#rollmean(1)
Error in rollmean(zoo(x), k, fill = fill, align = align, ...) : 
  argument "k" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @zhiweili specify the `fill = TRUE` in `rollmeanr`.  In your example data, there is only a single element per group, but if you have a larger dataset, it should work

Comment: thanks, I also check the documents, and I realize that I miss the `fill = T`.

Comment: @zhiweili with a single observation, it may return `TRUE` as output because the `NA` will be logical by default `NA_logical_`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228246/discussion-between-zhiwei-li-and-akrun).

Comment: @ akrun, Hi, I have a new problem. could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042824/can-not-use-non-standard-evaluation-in-self-define-function-in-r

Comment: @zhiweili sure, can you please specify the problem

Comment: this is the website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042824/can-not-use-non-standard-evaluation-in-self-define-function-in-r

Comment: @zhiweili I posted a solution there

Answer (score 0):

First I don't think your data should be grouped, at least for the data shared it doesn't make sense to have only 1 row in the group and then calculate `lag` value and rolling mean on it.

You can have appropriate column names using `.names` in `across` and use `map_dfc` to combine everything into one dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(zoo)

map_dfc(1:3, function(x) {
  aa %>% 
    transmute(across(.cols = contains('mean'), 
                  .fns = list(lag = ~lag(., x), 
                              lag0 = ~rollmeanr(., x, fill = NA)), 
                   .names = sprintf('{fn}_{col}_%d', x)))
  })
```

You can add `group_by(Region)` if you are trying it on some another dataset.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, Hi, I have a new problem, could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042824/can-not-use-non-standard-evaluation-in-self-define-function-in-r