# can not use Non-standard evaluation in self-define function in r

Tags: r, dplyr, model, evaluation

I want to write a function that extracts some information from `gam` model.
I can do this without self-define function (`df` is what I wanted):

```
library(mgcv)
library(tidyverse)
model = gam(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

result = summary(model)$p.table

estimate = result[2,1]
se = result[2,2]

df = data.frame(estimate = estimate, se = se)
df
```

Then I wrapped it with a self-define function:

```
my_gam <- function(y, x, data){
  
  model = gam(y ~ x, data = data)
  
  result = summary(model)$p.table
  
  estimate = result[2,1]
  se = result[2,2]
  
  df = data.frame(estimate = estimate, se = se)
  df
}
```

But I can not use my function correctly.

```
my_gam(y = mpg, x = cyl, data = mtcars)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'cyl' not found

```
my_gam(y = 'mpg', x = 'cyl', data = mtcars)
```

> Error in gam(y ~ x, data = data) :
> Not enough (non-NA) data to do anything meaningful

Is that a way I can get the `df` just as the first code block when I run `my_gam(y = mpg, x = cyl, data = mtcars)`.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reformulate`/`as.formula` to construct the formula.

```
library(mgcv)

my_gam <- function(y, x, data){
  model = gam(reformulate(x, y), data = data)
  result = summary(model)$p.table
  estimate = result[2,1]
  se = result[2,2]
  df = data.frame(estimate = estimate, se = se)
  df
}

my_gam(y = 'mpg', x = 'cyl', data = mtcars)
#   estimate     se
#1   -2.876 0.3224
```

Comment: it's a good way, but in my real situation, I have many non-standard variable names such as `J45_46.>=81`. How could I sove this error: `rename(mtcars, 'J45_46.>=81' = 'mpg');
f = reformulate('cyl', 'J45_46.>=81');
model = gam(f, data = mtcars)`

Comment: Ohh..that seems to be a different question. Maybe `gam` does not allow non-standard names, try renaming the columns to standard names then.

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a formula with `paste` which would be fast

```
my_gam <- function(y, x, data){
   model <- gam(as.formula(paste(y, "~", x)), data = data)
  result <- summary(model)$p.table
   estimate <- result[2,1]
  se <- result[2,2]
   df <- data.frame(estimate = estimate, se = se)
   df
  }

 my_gam(y = 'mpg', x = 'cyl', data = mtcars)
 #  estimate        se
 #1 -2.87579 0.3224089
```

---

Or another option is to pass a formula as argument

```
my_gam <- function(fmla, data){
   model <- gam(fmla, data = data)
  result <- summary(model)$p.table
   estimate <- result[2,1]
  se <- result[2,2]
   df <- data.frame(estimate = estimate, se = se)
   df
  }

 my_gam(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
#  estimate        se
# 1 -2.87579 0.3224089
```